# Finding the minimal product

Tags: c++, algorithm

How do you find the minimal product from an array? This is the problem I have and the attempted solution isn't working. What have I done wrong?

https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHRL4

> After visiting a childhood friend, Chef wants to get back to his home. Friend lives at the first street, and Chef himself lives at the `N`-th (and the last) street. Their city is a bit special: you can move from the `X`-th street to the `Y`-th street if and only if `1 <= Y - X <= K`, where `K` is the integer value that is given to you. Chef wants to get to home in such a way that the product of all the visited streets' special numbers is minimal (including the first and the `N`-th street). Please, help him to find such a product.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input consists of two integer numbers - `N` and `K` - the number of streets and the value of `K` respectively. The second line consist of `N` numbers - `A1, A2, ..., AN` respectively, where `Ai` equals to the special number of the `i`-th street.
>
> **Output**
>
> Please output the value of the minimal possible product, modulo `1000000007`.
>   Constraints
>
> `1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5`
>   `1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^5`
>   `1 ≤ K ≤ N`
>
> **Example**
>
> **Input:**
>
> 4 2
>   1 2 3 4.
>
> **Output:**
>   8

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int P(int A[], int N, int K) {
    if (N == 1) return A[0];

    int m = A[0], prod = m;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        if (1 <= A[i]-m && A[i]-m <= K) {
            prod *= A[i];
        }
    }
    return prod;
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << P(A, 4, 2);
}
```

I get 6 instead of 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such problems can typically be solved by Dynamic Programming:

1. Construct an appropriate state variable: Let the state be `S = current street`. Let the factor at street `S` be called`C_S`
2. For each state `S`, collect the possible actions: `a(S) = {go to any street T for which : 1 <= C_T - C_S <= K, T <=N }, a(N) = {}`.
3. Introduce a value function `V(S) = minimal product to get from S to N`. Set `V(N) = C_N`.

Having all this together, one can now solve the Bellman equation backwards from `N`, where particularly the value `V(0)` is sought:

```
V(S) = min_{allowed T} { V(T)*C_S }
```

Example implementation:

```
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    int K = 2;

    std::vector<int> C{1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> V(N);
    V.back() = C.back();

    for(int i = N - 2; i>= 0; --i)
    {
        int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); //possible overflow here,
                                                   //better change that
        for(int j=i+1; j< N; ++j)
        {
            double DeltaC = C[j] - C[i];
            if(DeltaC <= K && DeltaC >= 1)
            {
                double vt = V[j] * C[i];
                if(vt < min)
                {
                    min = vt;
                }
            }
        }
        V[i] = min;
    }

    std::cout<<V[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/008f325a666d6bd2)

The output is `8`.

Please understand the code, test it and then use it with a good conscience (whatever that means).

Comment: How do I learn to come up with abstractions like what you did in the beginning (and then learn to program it)? I would've never thought of this solution.

Comment: @templateboy: Dynamic Programming is from the first just the idea to start at the end and iterate to the beginning. Many would have written down just the central equation `V(S) = min_{allowed T} { V(T)*C_S }` (which in fact the Bellman equation). The whole state/action/reward thing is indeed a little abstraction, but it provides a systematic approach to set up and solving the Bellman equation, with which you can solve much more complicated (real-life) problems as well. If you're interested in DP: [here](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html) is a good book.